# Messages stuck in x-delayed-message Exchange on RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMq 3.6.5 and Erlang 19.0.
I have an `x-delayed-message` exchange set to send messages in at most 30 minutes to a queue.
I have waited for the message for a long time and after some research I have found the message in a DCL file `./db/rabbit@<my-host>-mnesia/rabbit_delayed_messagerabbit@<my-host>.DCL`

Is there a way to see what happened?

Also, I couldn't find an easy way to view the messages stored in Mnesia.
Thanks